# Using PHP site to post javascript code and it translates the code, resulting code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a php site that allows for javascript to be embeded. i have a function that won't work correctly in IE or chrome. Can you take a look at it and tell me if theres something wrong

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var counting = 0;
var totaltime;
var audio;
var timeout;
var settimer = 0;
var haystack = "|";
var needle;
function start_playing(a,b){ haystack = haystack+a+"|";
needle = a;
audio = document.getElementById(b);counting = counting + 1.0;   audio.play();
if(haystack.split(needle).length -1 >= 2){document.getElementById(a).value = "No Plays  Left";
document.getElementById(a).disabled = true;}else{document.getElementById(a).value = "Playing";
document.getElementById(a).disabled = true;totaltime = Math.round(audio.duration)*1000;
timeout = setTimeout("enable_button('"+a+"')",totaltime);}}function enable_button(a)   {document.getElementById(a).value ="Play"document.getElementById(a).disabled = false;}}
//]]>
</script>
<div>
<input id="PlayButton1" type="button" onclick="start_playing('PlayButton1','myTune1')" value="Play" /></div>
<audio id="myTune1" src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

what can be the issue?.  its supposed to be clicked,turn disabled for the duration of the song,then enable itself. after the second play it will say no plays left.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: So what is wrong with it? Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting any errors? Is something not working as intended?

Comment: Format well your code and you'll see you have syntax errors.

Comment: The 3 first comments are the same house with different colors lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've revised your code. This should work

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var counting = 0;
var totaltime;
var audio;
var timeout;
function start_playing(a,b){ 
    audio = document.getElementById(b);
    counting++;
    audio.play();
    if(counting == 2){
        document.getElementById(a).value = "No Plays Left";
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(a).value = "Playing";
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = true;
        totaltime = Math.round(audio.duration)*1000;
        timeout = setTimeout("enable_button('"+a+"')",totaltime);
    }
}

function enable_button(a){
    document.getElementById(a).value = "Play";
    document.getElementById(a).disabled = false;
}
//]]>
</script>
<div>
<input id="PlayButton1" type="button" onclick="start_playing('PlayButton1','myTune1')" value="Play" /></div>
<audio id="myTune1" src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

There are still unused variables though. Please format your code next time before submitting your answer.

Comment: I tried using this and i get a error..start_playing is undefined.

Comment: I tested it on an empty page with no other code and it works. Can you confirm this?